# How to Restore Octopus Deploy Database from a previous backup file

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, octopus-deploy

After an unplanned power cut, we have been unable to view details of all previous deployments via Octopus deploy. We attempted to restore the database using raven db studio to no avail.
we basically get an error as in the screenshot [image]

I'm wondering what the recommended way is , for performing backup restore.
ATM we cannot view details on the environments, projects and dashboard pages. They all come back blank. All our projects are not visible via  the projects drop-down menu as well.
[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prior to Octopus 2.0, the backup files produced by Octopus (*.octobak files) are RavenDB exports, not backups - this is because RavenDB backups really only work on the same/similar machine that created them, while exports can be imported on any machine.

However, you shouldn't perform the restore directly in RavenDB - we have a wizard for doing this:

https://octopus.com/docs/administration/backup-and-restore

The section on restore assumes you are restoring to a new server, but the process is exactly the same when restoring on an existing server. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Paul. the documentation says 'install as if' you were doing a new install. Does this mean downloading the most recent .msi or the the current running version of octopus. I have also tried clicking on the backup to initialize administrative tools (octopus restore tool), but that returns an error `could not start octopus tools` is there something i may be missing out?

Comment: Just to note that we are still running version 1.6.2.1722 of the octopus server.

Comment: As previously stated, we are running a previous version of octopus to the current version ATM, we do not want to upgrade just yet unless this becomes inevitable. I'm not sure at this point if the instructions  in the link provided , means that we have to assume we are installing the most current version.

Comment: If anyone encounters the `could not start octopus` error, you may need to run the restore tool via the command prompt.i.e `cd "Program Files\Octopus\Tools"` and then run the tool using `Tools.exe -restore`Select the backup file and then click `restore`